# Running Pandoc command through subprocess.run()

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pandoc

I am running a Pandoc command through python's `subprocess.run()` and find the command runs very slowly compared to running it on the terminal. It is instantaneous on the terminal and takes 16 seconds in python.

The larger the files the more time it takes. My test file is only 4K and it takes 2 seconds to process it.

I am sending the command as a list like so:

```
['pandoc', '--defaults=defaults.yaml', '--bibliography', 'bibliography.bib']
```

In addition without the `--bibliography` argument, the command runs faster probably due to less processing.

The other thing that I find puzzling is I tried `shell=True` just for kicks and the running time that took 16 seconds on my files came down to 2 seconds. I know `shell=True`is a big no-no and what I am looking for is answers or alternatives on why this command is running so slow and what I can do to remedy it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hypothesis: `pandoc-citeproc` is not in the PATH when running in the shell. A change to a different YAML library made pandoc-citeproc more correct but also significantly slower, so this might be what you see.

Comment: @tarlov Thanks for your reply but I am using the latest version of Pandoc 2.11.1.1 where citeproc is now part of Pandoc and no longer separate package.

Comment: does the time go down if you use `input-file --output output-file`? if so, it has to do with how python's subprocess handles stdin/out.. potentially you need to flush some buffer... shrug..